# What do you say when you want to ask cashier if something cost money?

Tags: expressions, expression-choice

Let's say you're at a store and cashier is ringing you up. The cashier asks you if you need a bag. And you want to ask if you have to pay for it. In this situation, normally what do you say? 
These are some questions I came up with.

> 1. Do I have to pay for it?
> 2. Does it cost any?
> 3. Do you charge for it?
> 4. Is it free?

I want to know what is the most natural way to say it. And please let me know if you have any suggestions. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The correct response, at a time when we have all come to realise that re-cycling is an imperative, not an option, is - "It's OK, I brought my own (reusable) bag".

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, I'd say:
"Does it cost extra?" or "Does it cost anything extra?" or "Is it free of charge?"

In other cases, where something feels more like an add-on, you might say "Is that included in the original price?" or "Is that included in the sticker price?" or "Does that come with *[main item you're purchasing]*?" (The last one, "come with," is especially common for food – e.g. "does that burger come with fries?")

Answer (score 0):

It can be asked as, "Is it chargeable?".

Comment: In American English, at least, I don't think that's a very common way to phrase it.

Comment: oh I see! I didn't know.

Answer (score -2):

In the given situation, "Does it cost any?" or "Do you charge for it?" sounds natural or you could even try "How much would that be?" so that if he actually charges for it he would just say the price or if it is for free he would just say "No sir, it is for free" and even you won't sound like you are after free stuff. Some people might feel so, So i thought I could mention it.